# How to get the tcp window size of a socket in linux?

Tags: c, linux, tcp

Is there a way in linux c api to get the incoming window size of your tcp socket?

To be clear, by incoming I mean from the perspective of my linux server.
It seems that the SND and RCV values in linux in my accepted socket are flipped, i.e. RCV means from the server to the client.
In this case I need the client to server side, which is SND.

`SND_BUF` and `RCV_BUF` seem unrelated to the actual value that is sent,
and `TCP_WINDOW_CLAMP` isn't accurate.

Comment: There might be, but I'm more curious about *why* you need it? What the *real* problem is? Please read [about the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Also please  read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I want to log connections with unusual window sizes without using raw sockets (along with other TCP parameters I had no problems getting).

Why isn't this question good?

Comment: Alos see ["getsockopt" "receive window" size site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22getsockopt%22+%22receive+window%22+size+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the internal tcp socket parameters with this (linux-specific, non-portable) socket option:

```
struct tcp_info ti;
socklen_t tisize = sizeof(ti);
getsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_INFO, &ti, &tisize);
```

The structure tcp_info is defined in `linux/tcp.h` and its member `ti.tcpi_rcv_space` contains the advertised tcp receive window for the corresponding socket.

Since Linux 4.8 there is a new tcp socket option `TCP_REPAIR_WINDOW`, which allows to read (and even set) the send and receive window directly:

```
struct tcp_repair_window trw;
socklen_t trwsize = sizeof(trw);
getsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_REPAIR_WINDOW, &trw, &trwsize);
```

Now the TCP send and receive window can be read from `trw.snd_wnd` and `trw.rcv_wnd`.

Comment: That's great, but I actually need to opposite side (the incoming). I don't see that there is tcpi_snd_space, but the tcpi_snd_wscale is correct.

Comment: @WimpyToes then why don't you say "send window"? "incoming" means "receive" in common terminology

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant incoming from the perspective of my linux server. these values seem to be from the perspective of the accepted sockets. I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: @WimpyToes there is a fairly recent option now which I added to the answer. It requires a kernel >= 4.8, however. I fear, that there is no other way.